# add value/number in a row value python csv

Tags: python

i hace a problem with a code, i need to add/sum/plus(1+1=2,this) "10" to a row value in a csv file

this is my code

```
import csv
import os
import random
import time
import copy
import sys
scriptname,f1name,f2name = sys.argv

#encabezados
fieldnames=["node_code","node_type","wlan_code","destination_id","x(m)","y(m)","z(m)","primary_channel","min_channel_allowed","max_channel_allowed","cw","cw_stage","tpc_min(dBm)","tpc_default(dBm)","tpc_max(dBm)","cca_min(dBm)","cca_default(dBm)","cca_max(dBm)","tx_antenna_gain","rx_antenna_gain","channel_bonding_model","modulation_default","central_freq (GHz)","lambda","ieee_protocol","traffic_load(pkts/s)"]

with open(f1name, 'r') as infile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=";",fieldnames=fieldnames)
    columns= next(reader)
    #print (columns)

    with open(f2name,"w") as outfile:
#Escribe los encabezados al archivo
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=";")
        writer.writeheader()
        memoria1={}
        memoria2={}

#escribe y guarda las filas 
        for row in reader:        
            if row['node_type']=='1':

               row['x(m)']=(row['x(m)']+str(int(10)))
               row['y(m)']=(row['y(m)']+str(int(10)))

            writer.writerow(row)    

print("correct")
```

but i have the next result,it only "paste" a 10 to the value

```
AP_A;0;A;-1;277;101;
STA_A1;1;A;-1;27710;10110;
```

i need to change this to

```
AP_A;0;A;-1;277;101;
STA_A1;1;A;-1;287;110;
```

i really apreciate if someone could help me 
thanks in advance!

Comment: _i need to add/sum/plus(1+1=2,this) "10"_ ..... _but i have the next result,it only "paste" a 10 to the value_ Isn't that just because you're converting the int to a string before adding it, in `+ str(int(10))` ? Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you done any debugging? Also, why use `;` as the delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the place where you are pasting '10' to the string value:

```
row['x(m)']=(row['x(m)']+str(int(10)))
```

Instead, you want to take the int value, add 10 to it, and turn it into a sting again, something like:

```
row['x(m)'] = str(10 + int(row['x(m)']))
```

Comment: _and turn it into a sting again_ I don't believe that's necessary. In fact, couldn't you simplify that entire line to `row['x(m)'] += 10` ?

Comment: Possibly. I don't know what the original contents was. In the code in the question it's being treated as a string, so I treated it as a string in my code too ...